# Android Studio ¿Como usar NestedScrollView con tabs y view pager?

Tags: android, android-studio, viewpager, scroll-view

**Descripción**

Tengo una Actividad la cual tiene dentro **Tabs y View Pager** los cuales son usados para intercambiar fragments. Los fragments tienen dentro **recycler views**. Me gustaría que se pueda deslizar desde la Actividad hacia abajo y este mismo "desliz" afecte a los recycler-view que están dentro de los fragments (los que se cargan en el view pager).

**Adjunto mi código xml de la Actividad con lo que estoy probando (lo cual no funciona):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:contentDescription="Ayuda">

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_foto"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/perfil"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_nombre"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Tomás Menniti"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#252525"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/img_foto"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_editar_perfil"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
            android:fontFamily="@font/arimo_bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:text="@string/editar_perfil"
            android:textColor="#4e342e"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/txt_nombre"/>

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="Ayuda"
            android:layout_below="@id/txt_editar_perfil">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabss_perfil"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#fafafa"
                android:contentDescription="Ayuda"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="#a1887f"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pagerr_perfil"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="Ayuda"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_below="@id/bar_layout"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Este código da el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imágen, al ejecutar mi app con dicho código xml, los fragments NO SE VEN. Es como si desapareciera el View pager. Esto es **A causa del agregado del *Nested Scroll View***

Si ejecuto la app sin el **Nested Scroll View**, esta funciona correctamente, mostrando los fragments sin ningún problema.

**Edit:**

Toda la pregunta se puede resumir en que lo que quiero lograr, es **exactamente** el mismo comportamiento de los perfiles de la **app. mobile Instagram**. Si conocen esta plataforma, sabrán que primero se aprecian los datos del usuario (lo que sería mi Actividad), luego están las tabs (fotos/igtv/fotos en las que te etiquetaron), y por último el view pager que hace los cambios de fragments.

**Gracias por leer!**

Comment: No puedes usar match_parent para definir el alto del relative que esta dentro del scroll, no tiene sentido decirle a algo que use todo el alto del padre cuando el padre tiene un alto variable dependiente del hijo, se genera una paradoja espacio tiempo.

Comment: Hola Erick, gracias por contestar nuevamente. Que debo hacer entonces para solucionarlo?. Igualmente creo que estás confundido o yo entendí mal, porque relative es hijo de scroll y scroll es hijo de drawer y los 3 tienen match_parent en height. Estás diciendome que el padre de relative tiene un alto variable pero no es así porque tiene match_parent. Por favor, necesito solucionar esto :((((

Comment: El scroll es matchparent, pero el contenido del scroll siempre es wrapcontent, sino no seria scrolleable, vos le pusiste a todo match_parent y justamente por eso se da la contradiccion.

Comment: Perdón, pero como tendría que hacer entonces para solucionar el problema?

Comment: Preparar todo lo de adentro para que sea wrap_content, no existe match_parent en un scroll, en Instagram como veras, el contenido es claramente wrap_content, mientras mas fotos tiene mas largo el scroll.